# How do I say "to vote for someone"/"voĉdoni por iu" without using the preposition "por", if the vote is not in favour of this person?

Tags: prepositions, ambiguity-reduction

The standard way to say "to vote for someone" is "voĉdoni por iu / voĉdoni iun". But if the vote is against that person, for exemple for banning this person from a community, the use of "por" can lead to some confusion. It is because "por" can be used to show someone who [benefits](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/aliaj_rolvortetoj/por.html#i-1kk) from the vote, but in this case this person does not benefit.

How do I express the idea of voting for someone without this risk of confusion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the vote is about whether the person should be affected in a negative way, e.g. be banned from a commnunity, one can say "voĉdoni kontraŭ iu".